# Showing that an algorithm is correct

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy

Suppose we have n sellers and m buyers sorted in increasing order. We say that a seller s and buyer b "match" if s < b. Find the maximum subset A consisting of matched pairs (exactly one buyer and seller can be matched).

My algorithm is greedy and works by selecting the first seller s1 and finding the first buyer b1 at position c such that s1 < b1 and adding that to A. Then we move to the second seller s2 and iterate from c+1 in buyers until we find a buyer b2 such that s2 < b2. We do this until the position c is equal to the size of the buyers list.

I'm just having trouble proving that the algorithm is correct. I'm not sure how to formalize the method so that it can be easily seen that the optimal solution is always found. When I think about it, it makes sense, but again the formal verification is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Formal verification is *hard*.

Comment: I would recommend trying to translate that into code or at least pesudo code and ask the same question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

"Formal" proof is sort of a vague description. I'll sketch a proof to roughly the level of detail that would appear in a research paper (which may be less than the level of detail required for a problem set in an algorithms course).

The greedy algorithm clearly produces a valid matching. (As a result of the difficulties of formal methods in practice, this is indeed an abuse of the word "clearly".)

To show that this matching is of maximum size, we prove the following technical statement by induction. For all k not greater than this size, there exists a maximum matching where the k least sellers are matched as in the greedy matching.

The base case is k = 0. We can take any old maximum matching, since the statement is vacuously true (0 least is the empty set).

The inductive step is, for k > 0, to prove that the statement for k - 1 implies the statement for k. There exists a maximum matching M that agrees with the greedy solution on the k - 1 least sellers, but perhaps not the kth least, which we'll call sk. Now comes a case argument.

Case 1: sk is matched in M and in the greedy solution. Let bG be sk's buyer in the greedy solution and bM be sk's buyer in M. If bG = bM, then we're done. Otherwise, bG < bM, because the greedy solution chose the minimum eligible buyer among all buyers excluding only the buyers for s1, ..., sk-1 (which are matched the same way in M). If bG is available in M, then switch sk's buyer to bG. Otherwise, swap bG with bM in M; the seller previously buying from bG gets a greater buyer, so the swap is valid.

Case 2: sk is matched in M but not in the greedy solution. Then the greedy solution is a subset of M. This is impossible, because sk's buyer in M is available in the greedy solution (the greedy solution is maximal).

Case 3: sk is not matched in M. Some greater seller is matched; replace it with sk and apply one of the other cases.